# Convert an array of strings into datetimes with different formats

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python function to convert an array of strings into an array of `datetime` objects where string can be in one of two formats, and would like to know how the following code can be optimized:

```py
import datetime


def con(data) -> list:
    op = []
    for i in data:
        if len(i) <= 8:
            try:
                op.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%d/%m/%y"))
            except:
                pass
        else:
            try:
                op.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%d/%m/%Y"))
            except:
                pass
    return op


inputs = ['20/05/25', '20/05/25', '29/02/2000', '19/02/2034']

inputs = con(inputs)
print(inputs)
```

Comment: A minor point that I believe should be in an answer: avoid using a bare `except:` (that is, an exception handler that doesn't specify one or more exception classes), especially if the handler is just `pass`. See [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice? on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553825/573255) for more details.

Answer (score 9):

## Divide and conquer

Your function does too much at once. Your core problem is parsing a date from a set of possible formats. Let's start there:

```py
from contextlib import suppress
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Iterable


def try_parse_date(text: str, formats: Iterable[str]) -> datetime:
    """Attempt to parse a date from given formats."""

    for frmt in formats:
        with suppress(ValueError):
            return datetime.strptime(text, frmt)

    raise ValueError("Could not parse date from formats.")
```

This functions takes the to-be parsed string and a list of formats to try one after another.
It will return the parsed datetime, once a datetime has been successfully parsed. If a datetime could not be parsed with any of the given formats, it will raise an appropriate exception.

## Use standard library tools

Then we can apply this to our input. Since we want to parse all strings with the same formats, we can use `functools.partial` to bind the formats of the function to a new function `parser` and then call that function on all elements of the `input` list within a list comprehension to create our `output` list:

```py
from contextlib import suppress
from datetime import datetime
from functools import partial
from typing import Iterable


def try_parse_date(text: str, formats: Iterable[str]) -> datetime:
    """Attempt to parse a date from given formats."""

    for frmt in formats:
        with suppress(ValueError):
            return datetime.strptime(text, frmt)

    raise ValueError("Could not parse date from formats.")


inputs = ['20/05/25', '20/05/25', '29/02/2000', '19/02/2034']
parser = partial(try_parse_date, formats=["%d/%m/%y", "%d/%m/%Y"])
outputs = [parser(s) for s in inputs]
print(outputs)
```

Note that I also renamed the output variable to have a descriptive name (it's not the *input*).

Comment: I missed some nuance in my answer that I'll add later tonight, but in the meantime - I think the only thing missing from this answer is that your final `raise` should include a `from` with a reference to the last inner exception.

Comment: @Reinderien: Should it? I would argue that all formats are equal here, we have no idea which would produce the better error message (ie, which is closest to the actual data). I would, however, be in favor of enriching the exception with both the failing value _and_ the formats it was tried against. The current one lacks a lot of information.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That advice is coupled with "only call `strptime` once", since OP's actual use case is significantly less generic than this solution would lead us to believe.

Comment: @Reinderien: Well, that's a very different solution then. If `strptime` is only called once, there's no point in suppressing the exception it throws and raising a custom one. For the solution at hand -- which doesn't "poke" and instead uses a list of formats -- then I would argue that using `from` with a single exception would be possibly misleading, and thus worse than not using `from` at all.

Comment: I feel like [Exception Groups](https://peps.python.org/pep-0654/) would be a good fit for this kind of generic approach… `excs = []; for …: try: return datetime.… except ValueError as e: excs.append(e)` then, if nothing returns `raise ExceptionGroup('Could not parse date from formats', excs)`

Answer (score 8):

Don't rely on datetime parsing to throw a `ValueError` to determine which format you follow. Among other reasons, this is problematic because it will also throw-and-suppress for complete nonsense that you should instead be noisy about. Even if you throw a generic exception after having exhausted all other formats, this is not ideal because the exception comes from your code and not the `datetime` code. In the ideal case, whenever possible, it should be `datetime` itself at the top of the exception trace. Trace quality matters quite a bit, and encouraging sane exception traces is a gift from your current self to your future debugging self.

Since there is no built-in optional-century year field, detect it explicitly during parse. In the ideal implementation, expend the minimum amount of effort to discriminate between year styles while leaving as much of the full parsing as possible to `datetime`. (Your top-level `len` is not reliable enough, I think, because it's influenced by varying month and day digit counts.)

Add (more) type hints to your function signature, and produce a `date`, not a `datetime`.

Produce an iterator instead of appending to a list.

Add unit tests.

```py
import datetime
from typing import Iterable, Iterator


def convert_dates(data: Iterable[str]) -> Iterator[datetime.date]:
    for string in data:
        year = string.rsplit(sep='/', maxsplit=1)[-1]
        if len(year) <= 2:
            year_field = '%y'
        else:
            year_field = '%Y'
        yield datetime.datetime.strptime(
            string, '%d/%m/' + year_field,
        ).date()


def test() -> None:
    inputs = ('20/05/25', '29/02/2000', '19/02/2034')
    actual = tuple(convert_dates(inputs))
    expected = (
        datetime.date(2025, 5, 20),
        datetime.date(2000, 2, 29),
        datetime.date(2034, 2, 19),
    )
    assert actual == expected

    try:
        tuple(convert_dates(['nonsense']))
        raise AssertionError('should have thrown')
    except ValueError as e:
        assert 'does not match format' in e.args[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: While I don't agree with your assessment on using `ValueError`s to skip failing formats, I really like the regex approach.

Comment: Thanks. I do recognize that ask-for-forgiveness-instead-of-permission is pretty typical in Python, but applied here it will hide more severe problems in the data. OP has not given any explicit indication as to where the data come from and what guarantees they have about being well-formed, so as diligent developers we should operate from a strict validation standpoint until we need otherwise.